# Child element loses floating when parent element's position is fixed

Tags: html, css

I am creating a navigation panel that'll stay fixed when scrolling down. Here's the code.

```
<header>
    <a class="logo" href="/">Logo_name</a>
    <nav>
        <a href="#">Menu_1</a>
        <a href="#">Menu_2</a>
    </nav>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</header>
```

And here's the css

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    max-width:960px;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
}
nav {
    float: right;
}
```

I want to have the logo on the right side and the navigation menus on the right side.

Right now, the float seem to work, but the nav elements appear right after the logo instead of being floated to the right edge.

If I remove the position:fixed code from header, the floating seems to work fine.

Comment: why not you use display: inline-block;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @AngelMdez, Flexbox is a better way to go than Floats, `position: fixed` should work all the same; just keep in mind that you should specify a width so the element itself uses the space you expect.

After that you can remove all the `float` and `clear` properties and it should be fine.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a class="logo" href="/">Logo_name</a>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Menu_1</a>
    <a href="#">Menu_2</a>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="content">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

**Original Example with Floats**

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: 60px;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a class="logo" href="/">Logo_name</a>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Menu_1</a>
    <a href="#">Menu_2</a>
  </nav>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</header>

<div class="content">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding both max-width and width property to header worked.

Comment: Good to know, try to get familiarized with Flexbox, IMO it should help you a lot more building layouts than Floats... after that, research a bit about CSS Grid as well so you get more tools to work with under your belt

Comment: Sure, but any idea why this float didn't work with position:fixed. I remember this working quite a number of years back. Not sure what happened now.

Comment: Actually it still worked; try adding the `width:100%` and `max-width` to your original code and add some content to scroll, it should stick to the top as well... its just that (IMO) using floats to build this kind of components should be avoided since they behave awkwardly sometimes, and Flexbox is actually intended for this cases (one-dimensional alignment)

Comment: @mjustin I added the example with floats to the answer, check it out... I just added a background and height to make the bar more noticeable

Answer (score 1):

This would be the solution using flexbox instead of float:

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

nav {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a class="logo" href="/">Logo_name</a>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Menu_1</a>
    <a href="#">Menu_2</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

And you will need to remove the clear: both; from the HTMl. Let me know if it works!

Comment: I need to have a static header panel with position:fixed. Wwhen position is fixed the alignments doesn't work even with flexbox. In fact, float aligns them better than flexbox when position:fixed is removed.

Comment: @mjustin It should work unless you have something else affecting the element

Comment: Adding "position: fixed;" to the header should do it. If not, something is afection the header.

Comment: width:960px isn't responsive. It should me max-width:960px; When this is changed, it doesn't work.

Comment: Set "width: 100%" and "max-width" to whatever you need. 960px in the example. I've updated the code above.

Answer (score 0):

**To answer your question:** Most HTML elements have default styling provided by the browser called the *User Agent*. The `<header>` has a default `display` value of `display: block;`. An element with `display: block` grows to its maximum width relative to its container.

In this case the container of `<header>` is the `<body>` which takes its width from the `<html>` which takes up the whole *viewport*.

Because you've set the `max-width` to `960px` the element will grow to only 960px. This works fine, as the width is normally taking up the whole viewport. But as soon as you set an absolute position, in this case `fixed, the element is taken out of the normal document flow. Because it's now sticking to a fixed position. Meaning that it has no parent with a width. So it loses its inherited width by its parent ( the body ).

To solve your problem with the code you've already written, just add a width to the element. Because you've already set a `max-width: 960px;` you can tell the element to grow to 100% with: `width: 100%;`. It will stop at 960px because that's its maximum-width:

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

a {
  color: white;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
}
nav {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <a class="logo" href="/">Logo_name</a>
    <nav>
        <a href="#">Menu_1</a>
        <a href="#">Menu_2</a>
    </nav>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</header>
```